# Unable to add line with sed?

Tags: sed

I am trying to add this block to after my first line in a file:

```
sed -i '1a\
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' \
repositories { \
  maven { \
    url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' \
  } \ 
}' test.txt;
```

But on running interminal I get error:

**sed: -e expression #1, char 108: unexpected `}'**

Comment: apart from issue of using single quotes within single quotes, other issues may crop up as well.. I would suggest to put the lines you want to add to a file and use `sed '1r lines.txt' test.txt` which would be robust solution for all cases...

Comment: Remove the space behind the last backslash should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two things,

- You are including single quotes within single quotes, it will have undesirable results. Use double quotes or properly quote single quotes within the string.
- Nothing should follow the `\` at the end of the lines.

We could write something like,

```
sed "1a \\
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' \\
repositories { \\
  maven { \\
    url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' \\
  } \\
}" input
```

**Note** Here `\\` is required as we are using double quotes.

Comment: @User101 I omitted `-i` just to prevent accidental editing of the input file.

Comment: `s/including single quotes within single quotes, it will have undesirable results/you CANNOT include single quotes within single quotes/` and `s/or properly quote single quotes/or jump back out of the script with a closing single quote then provide a single quote in shell and then re-enter the script with an opening single quote/`. `'foo'\''bar'`, which I assume is what you had in mind, is not escaping the quote in the script it's exiting the script, providing an escaped single quote in the shell and then reentering the script.